# Why Mongodb returns OperationFailure error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I've a Rails application that gets data from Mongo. It returns error when trying to export the data to csv -

error": "internal-server-error",

"exception": "Mongo::Error::OperationFailure : Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit. (96)"

Created few indexes on the collection but its still throwing this error.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: MongoDB limits [in-memory sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations) operations to 32MB.  You need to create an index that will support the sort, or match fewer documents when sorting.

Comment: Index support the sort. I confirmed it with db.collection.find().sort({'vid':-1}).limit(4000).    Its a problem when I try to access more than 4000 records through app

Comment: Umm, no, the error message clearly states `Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM`.  Check with `db.collection.explain().find().sort({'vid':-1})`.   If the index supports the sort, there will not be a stage to sort or to generate sort keys.
make sure the collection has an index where `vid` is the first key in the spec.

Comment: Adding the index on the sort field fixed the issue. Thanks